# SPSS Loop: parse n variables for list of values

Tags: loops, spss

I want to loop through multiple variables (ie multiple haystacks) using a list of needles.

Data:

| PICK1 | PICK2 | PICK3 | PICK4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grape | Raspberry | Clementime | Strawberry |
| Strawberry | Lemon | Blueberry | Apple |
| Cantelope | Mango | Grape | Pear |
| Apple | Orange | Kiwi | Raspberry |

Manual code that works

```
Compute citrus=0
if char.index(PICK1,"orange")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK2,"orange")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK3,"orange")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"orange")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK1,"lemon")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK2,"lemon")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK3,"lemon")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"lemon")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"clementine")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"clementine")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"clementine")>0 citrus=1.
if char.index(PICK4,"clementine")>0 citrus=1.
```

Desired Outcome: log 1 if the values are found within the variables

| Citrus |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

Attempted code (not working)

```
do repeat L = [orange, lemon, clementine]
 /PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
compute L = if char.index(PICK,L)>0 citrus=1.
end repeat.
```

---

I originally put the char.index to search for multiple values with a similar basename. For example, searching "berry" would desire to find "strawberry", "blueberry", etc. Is there a way to incorporate that into the `COMPUTE` function?

```
NUMERIC berry (f1.0).
DO REPEAT  PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
COMPUTE berry=any(PICK, char.index(PICK, "berry").
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do repeat` structure operates with arrays which must be of equal lengths. On top of that, you do not need square brackets, and strings are referenced between quotations signs. Also, not sure if the `compute` really works like that, mixed with and `if` transformation.

You want to parse a list of variables, check for 3 strings, and do a transformation if condition is met:

```
NUMERIC citrus (f1.0).
COMPUTE citrus=0.
DO REPEAT  PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
IF any(PICK, "orange", "lemon", "clementine") citrus=1.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

or, a little more synthetic:

```
NUMERIC citrus (f1.0).
DO REPEAT  PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
COMPUTE citrus=any(PICK, "orange", "lemon", "clementine").
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

or, if you want to also look at any "berries":

```
NUMERIC citrus (f1.0).
NUMERIC berries (f1.0).
DO REPEAT  PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
COMPUTE citrus=any(PICK, "orange", "lemon", "clementine").
COMPUTE berries = CHAR.INDEX(PICK, "berry")>0.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Thank you! The loop function works perfectly.  I originally put the char.index to search for multiple values with a similar base name. For example, searching "berry" would desire to find "strawberry", "blueberry", etc. Is there a way to incorporate that in to the COMPUTE function? 


NUMERIC berry (f1.0).
DO REPEAT  PICK = PICK1 to PICK7000.
COMPUTE berry=any(PICK, char.index(PICK, "berry").
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.

Comment: Yes there is, but please change the original question and add this as a separate question; otherwise the answer would not answer the question...

Comment: Added. Thanks again!

Comment: You could also accept the answer as the correct answer - the big green check mark on the left side of the answer ;)